# Matlab: Remove IF-ELSE Conditional statements using Logical Indexing

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, conditional-statements, vectorization

I don't understand precisely how I would do this question without using if statements or loops.

```
n = input ('What is the vector length? ');
y = rand(n,1);
x = rand(n,1);
p = zeros(n,1);
for i=1:n
    if (y(i) > 0.5 && x(i) < 0.5) || y(i) < 0.2
        p(i) = y(i) + x(i);
    else
        p(i) = (y(i)*x(i))^2
    end
end
```

a) Reimplement
the code using only vector operations and logical indexing (i.e., you
cannot use any loops or branches).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This way and you won't be needed to initialize `p` -

```
cond1 = (y > 0.5 & x < 0.5) | y < 0.2;
p = cond1.*(y + x) + ~cond1.*((y.*x).^2)
```

Comment: I've never seen a condition statement defined as a variable before. Is that a standard function of matlab?

Comment: @Thallazar Welcome to `MATLAB`, should I say? Yeah, that's how high MATLAB can get :) On a serious note, yes that's one of the tricks to remove conditional statements. `cond1` in this case stores the conditional decisions as a binary array and that we are mapping onto the two array values, which are values when the decision is true and false respectively.

Comment: Is there a name for them so I can read up on how they work? For instance, if you define it as some condition with y and x, does it only work with variables called y and x?

Comment: The name in the manual is a `logical array`.  You'll also find some good stuff under the function `find`, which converts a logical array to a list of indices of elements that are `true`.  Also read the entire "Users's Guide" section on "Matrices and Arrays", under the Mathematics chapter.  All that stuff is difficult to categorize.  You just have to familiarize yourself with the syntax.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for sharing with us this useful info!

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, you've helped me out immensly.

Comment: @Thallazar Make sure to accept answers that have helped out on the expectations of questions. It helps `SO` community at large. You can do this by clicking on the check button on the left of the answer.