# Replace vector elements using condition/if in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, replace, conditional-statements

I would like to replace the elements of an vector using a condition or if function.

a = [10 20 60];

if a < 30 = 4 else a = 5

the result needs to look like this:

b = [4 4 5]

Comment: btw you haven't specified what you want to happen for the number 30.

Comment: Hi Dan, I apologise, I stated the second part if my the if statement wrong, I will edit it.  Thank you for marking this as a duplicate, I do however would like to mention that I do prefer @Divakar answer.  He might however have to amend his answer I think, after I have edited my question.  I do apologise for the inconvenience.  Kind Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution using `logical indexing` -**

```
cond1 = a < 30
cond2 = a > 30
b = 4.*cond1 + 5.*(cond2) + a.*(~(cond1 | cond2))
```

**Short explanation:** `cond1` and `cond2` form the logical arrays based on the `IF-ELSE` conditions, which are used for indexing and form a numeric array of "scaled" values of `4 or 5`, while keeping `30`.

**One-liner version:** If you are into one-liners, this might feed your interest -

```
b = 4.*(a < 30) + 5.*(a > 30) + a.*(~(a > 30 | a < 30))
```

**Example #1**

```
a =
    10    20    60    30
b =
     4     4     5    30
```

Another related interesting question - [Matlab: Remove IF-ELSE Conditional statements using Logical Indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23133948/3293881)

Comment: thank you very much that is exactly what I was looking for, as you proposed I will as well study the logical indexing. Regards

Comment: @Crysthius Awesome! Glad it worked for you. Look into `logical indexing`, it's a powerful tool! Added one link in the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Another version using [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/):

```
a = [10 20 60];

b = a;
b(b < 30) = 4;
b(b >= 30) = 5;
```

Comment: One correction: the last line should be "greater than or equal to": `b(b >= 30) = 5;`